# xpath for a specific part a div

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

i have the following part html document and html document

```
<div class="boxContent">
 <div class="boxBold">Name1</div>
 Cat            
 <div class="boxBold">Name2</div>
 Dog                        
 <div class="boxBold">ID</div>
 749 X
</div>
```

i am trying to get the value `709 X` and ignore everything else, is there a standard to do that?

when i try to get the innertext of the parent div it gives me `CatDog749 X`

i tried `myDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='boxContent']").InnerText`
but what is the relation between the third child div and `749 X`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath will select the text following the `div` containing "ID" within a `div` of class "boxContent":

```
//div[@class='boxContent']/div[. = 'ID']/following-sibling::text()
```

Notes

- If multiple classes might be on the boxContent `div`, use
  `contains()` instead of simple equality testing.
- If there could be multiple `div`s of class "boxContent", hone
  selection or iterate over all, per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

myDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(//div[@class='boxContent']**[3]**).InnerText

Answer (score 0):

You get `CatDog749 X` because you choose **all** the nodes that have class `boxContent`, You need to choose the specific div.

XPath: `//div[@class='boxContent']/last()` : Get the last node in the div: `749 X`